# If a linear transformation $T$ is nilpotent, show that $\alpha_0+\alpha_1T+......+\alpha_kT^k$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

If a linear transformation $T$ is nilpotent, show that $\alpha_0+\alpha_1T+......+\alpha_kT^k$ is invertible provided that $0\ne\alpha_0\in F,$ for some field $F$. I am in the mid way, and am stuck at the point that if $S=\alpha_1T+......+\alpha_kT^k$ and $T^r=0$ for some $r$, then $S^r=0.$ Any help is welcome !!

Comment: You need to assume $\alpha_0$ is invertible (non-zero if you are working over a field), otherwise this obviously won't work.

Comment: Yeah !! Thanks !! I missed out that !! I have edited it !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that $\alpha_0$ is an invertible scalar, you may as well assume it to be$~1$ (multiplying by the invertible scalar $\alpha_0^{-1}$ will make it so, and doesn't change whether your polynomial in $T$ is invertible). Now $S$ is a commuting multiple of $T$ (namely $S=TY=YT$ where $Y=\alpha_1+\alpha_2T+\cdots+\alpha_kT^{k-1}$), so $T^r=0$ implies $S^r=0$ (namely $S^r=(TY)^r=TYTYTY\ldots=T^rY^r=0$). So you're down to showing $1+S$ is invertible if $S$ is nilpotent. But writing down the (geometric) series in $S$ for $(1+S)^{-1}$, which breaks off by nilpotency of $S$, gives you the inverse (concretely, it is $1-S+S^2-\cdots+(-S)^{r-1}$). There is no need to do any linear algebra (in spite of that tag to the question).

Comment: Just a small clarification !! If T is a linear transformation then does the following hold ? $(\alpha_1T+\alpha_2 T^2+....+\alpha_kT^k)^r=\alpha_1T^r+\alpha_2(T^r)^2+.....\alpha_k(T^r)^k$

Comment: It is not true in general...for verification take first two term and r=2..verify that right hand side is not equal to left hand side..

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen, "S is a multiple of T", so $T^r=0 \implies S^r=0$. How ???

Comment: @Abstraction: No, taking $r$-th powers does not work its way down into individual linear transformations (just like $(ax+by)^r\neq ax^r+by^r$ in general even for scalars). However everything in sight commutes here, so you can just work out $(\alpha_1T+\alpha_2 T^2+....+\alpha_kT^k)^r$ as a polynomial in $T$. But you don't really have to do that; I have updated my answer (with some emphasis on the use of commutation) explaning the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: In order to see that $S^r=0$, consider the [Multinomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). As for showing that $A=\alpha_0+\alpha_1T+......+\alpha_kT^k$ is invertible when $\alpha_0\neq 0$, consider the [Schur Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) of $A$ and $S$.